# New If Statement after If Else Block In a Function Return Unexpected Results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get a function to return 1 for weekdays, 2 for weekends and 3 for holidays. 
If holiday fall on weekdays, I want it to return as 3. 
I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime

def type(d):
    if d.weekday() in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        return 1         # return type 1, weekdays
    else:
        return 2         # return type 2, weekends
    if d in (datetime(2014, 1, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 5, 26), \
            datetime(2014, 7, 4), \
            datetime(2014, 9, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 11, 27), \
            datetime(2014, 12, 25)):
        return 3         # return type 3, holidays

print type(datetime(2014, 1, 1))     # return 1 instead of 3
```

Then I replaced else with just if, still get the same results:

```
def type(d):
    if d.weekday() in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        return 1         # return type 1, weekdays
    if d.weekday() in [5, 6]:
        return 2         # return type 2, weekends
    if d in (datetime(2014, 1, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 5, 26), \
            datetime(2014, 7, 4), \
            datetime(2014, 9, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 11, 27), \
            datetime(2014, 12, 25)):
        return 3         # return type 3, holidays
```

Comment: Please specify your output

Comment: Thanks for all the comment ! It works when checking holidays first. My question is why the second method (three if statements) won't work.  What's reason the third if statement never got checked?

Comment: The third if statement would never work as the method has already returned a value from the first if statement. When a method returns a value no code below that is executed . Rule of thumb a method should always have only one entry and one exit(one return statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check should go from the specific to the general. In this case that means that you should check for a holiday before checking for a weekday or a weekend.

```
from datetime import datetime

def day_type(d):
    if d in (datetime(2014, 1, 1),
            datetime(2014, 5, 26),
            datetime(2014, 7, 4),
            datetime(2014, 9, 1),
            datetime(2014, 11, 27),
            datetime(2014, 12, 25)):
        return 3         # return type 3, holidays
    elif d.weekday() in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        return 1         # return type 1, weekdays
    else:
        return 2         # return type 2, weekends
```

Also, you don't need those backslashes to continue your lines - the surrounding `(` and `)` make that unnecessary. And `type` is a builtin in Python, so rename your function to something like `day_type()` so that you don't shadow `type()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the holidays first:

```
from datetime import datetime
def type(d):
    if d in (datetime(2014, 1, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 5, 26), \
            datetime(2014, 7, 4), \
            datetime(2014, 9, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 11, 27), \
            datetime(2014, 12, 25)):
        return 3
    if d.weekday() in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
print type(datetime(2014, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate approach would be to check for holidays , then weekends and else for week days

```
def type(d):

    if d in (datetime(2014, 1, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 5, 26), \
            datetime(2014, 7, 4), \
            datetime(2014, 9, 1), \
            datetime(2014, 11, 27), \
            datetime(2014, 12, 25)):
        daytype = 3          # return type 3, holidays
    elif d.weekday() in [5,6]:
        daytype = 2         # return type 2, weekends
    else:
        daytype =  1    # return type 3 weekdays

    return daytype
```